# Curvature blow up along Ricci flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the book on Ricci flow by Andrews and Hopper, it has been proved that if Ricci flow on $M$ has a finite time singularity at time $T$ then $\lim_{t \nearrow T} \sup_{x\in M} |Rm(x,t)|=\infty$. I am wondering whether the following assertions are false or unknown (I know that the following assertions are true if $\lim$ is replaced by $\lim \sup$):

1. $\lim_{t \nearrow T} \sup_{x\in M} |Ric(x,t)|=\infty$
2. $\lim_{t \nearrow T} \sup_{x\in M} |R(x,t)|=\infty$ when $M$ is K\"{a}hler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Assertion (1) holds; that is, $Ric$ remains bounded as long as the Ricci flow exists. This was proved by N. Sesum ([AJM, 2005](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311397.pdf)), and improves the earlier result of R. Hamilton mentioned in the question which guarantees that $Rm$ stays bounded while the flow exists.

Comment: Does not $Ric$ is unbounded on $M \times [0,T)$ imply $\lim \sup_{t \nearrow T} \sup_{x\in M} |Ric(x,t)|=\infty$ ?

Comment: @Bingo: The statement (similarly to Hamilton's) is that if $Ric$ is bounded, then Ricci flow can continue for a little bit longer. Thus, if a finite time singularity is reached, then $Ric$ must blow up.